# How to run arbitrary code when the first item is placed into a java ExecutorService thread queue and when the last item is removed?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have an Executor (obtained via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`).  I would like to run some arbitrary code whenever a) the queue is empty and an item is inserted into the queue, and b) the queue is non-empty and the last item in the queue is removed.  Both a) and b) should always be run whenever their respective conditions are met, eg. if the queue is emptied and filled multiple times, a) and b) will be run multiple times.

All of this should be invisible to the user of the executor, which implies the code should probably be inside some sort of wrapper that implements ExecutorService.  I can wrap the result of `newFixedThreadPool()` before returning it to the user, if I want.  I can also implement my own ExecutorServicee entirely if necessary.

I want to be absolutely certain that a) and b) behave properly with respect to synchronization across multiple threads.  It's not clear to me the best way to do this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As a start, it sounds like all you want is to decorate the BlockingQueue implementation used by the executor such that when add(), offer(), etc. is called and the queue isEmpty(), you do a), and when remove(), take(), etc. is called, resulting in the queue's being isEmpty(), you do b). You might even find such a queue implementation out there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that was my thinking exactly.  The details about how to accomplish that correctly with regard to synchronization was the part that eluded me.

Comment: If by "synchronization", you mean "thread-safety", then as long as you're using a concurrent collection like LinkedBlockingQueue, it's "safe", though you might want to use a [CountdownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to ensure a) and b) only happen once, exactly when they're supposed to. Otherwise you may get multiple calls to a) or b).

Comment: I don't believe LinkedBlockingQueue has an atomic size+put or size+take operation, so I would still have to do some manual synchronization, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, hence the latch or semaphore. I suppose you could also extend the queue, adding appropriate `synchronized` methods, but then you're losing the efficiency of using a concurrent collection to begin with.

Comment: I think the desired behaviour intrinsically precludes a highly concurrent implementation. In a situation where several threads are withdrawing tasks, you only want one to trigger the queue-is-emptied condition, and that means there has to be some sort of coordination between the threads.

Comment: @Tom: True, but you should be able to limit the coordination to the times when it's important so that it doesn't otherwise impede concurrency--assuming it's important enough to make the effort.